# Is there a way to wait for an action in redux-sagas?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a saga (A) which fetches the API. This is tied with action (a). I want to trigger an action (b) which internally calls (a), waits for it to finish and then `yield` something.

```
// saga A -> action_a
function *saga_a(action) {
  yield put( ...action1...);
  yield call(api, ...params);
  yield put( ...action2...);
}


// saga B -> action_b
function *saga_b(action) {
  yield put(..action3..)

  waitFor -- put(action_a)     <------ how to achieve this?

  yield put(..action4..)
 }
```

Comment: Does `await put(action_a)` work?

Comment: Is there a way without `await`?

Answer (score 23):

Yes, there is. You can use `take` to achieve this.

```
function *saga_b(action) {
  ...

  yield take('action_a') // this will put the saga_b essentially on hold until `action_a` is handled by the reducer

  ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can use [saga-toolkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saga-toolkit) in order to `put` and *wait for* actions without `take`-ing them:

```
const resultOfFetchSomething = yield putAsync(fetchSomething()) // dispatches action "fetchSomething" & wait for the saga that is attached to it to finish running
```

Comment: to be clear, its held off until `action_a` is handled by reducer

Comment: `take(patternOrChannel): argument [object Object] is not valid channel or a valid pattern`... In which world where you able to `take` an action? also `put(action); take('actionType');` doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

The way I do it my code bases is by calling the other saga directly. It unfortunately couples the two together, but since you need to wait the coupling will at least be more explicit.

```
function *saga_b(action) {
  yield put(..action3..)
  yield call(saga_a, action_a)
  yield put(..action4..)
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I was hoping for a cleaner way of doing it. But I guess there is none. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use **call** instead **put** and call directly SAGA generator instead action, like:

```
yield call(saga_a, {payload: {param1: "param_one", param2: "param_two"}, type: 'unique_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but I struggled with the same thing and believe people still have the same problem. I had to write my own extensions to achieve this functionality. see https://github.com/kutlugsahin/redux-saga-callback

Eventually you will be able to do this

```js
// saga B -> action_b
function *saga_b(action) {
  yield put(..action3..)

  yield putWait(action_a)     <------ how to achieve this?

  yield put(..action4..)
 }
```

Comment: There's a package that also solves this issue (with `putAsync`) among others: https://www.npmjs.com/package/saga-toolkit